# How to delete files from iPhone's document directory which are older more than two days

Tags: iphone

I have an App in which I record the sound files and store it in apps Document Directory.

What I want is, it should contain only yesterday and to days older files and remove all others from the folder in iPhone app. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks ..

Comment: **Have you tried any thing by yourself?**

Comment: i have been looking to get something related but i have not find anything such that

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935582/delete-all-files-and-folder-from-a-certain-folder

Comment: @DilshadAlmani : Then how does amleszk found duplicate ? **What is your try?**

Comment: @Devang :I think. He has not asked duplicate question. He missed proper description.

Comment: @anonymous: Yes! title differs from description. And seems title is possible duplicate :)

Comment: I edited Title and description. I would take my downvote after Edit. Right now its locked. :-|

Comment: @DilshadAlmani: Please see my updated answer. I verified and posted working code. And sorry for misinterpretation. I took my downvote back after editing your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please look at the following code.

```
//Get the Document directory path.
 #define kDOCSFOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]

//Delete files by iterating items of the folder.
NSFileManager* fm = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fm enumeratorAtPath:kDOCSFOLDER];    
NSError* err = nil;
BOOL res;

NSString* file;
while (file = [en nextObject]) {
            // Date comparison.
    NSDate   *creationDate = [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:nil] fileCreationDate];
    NSDate *yesterDay = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(-1*24*60*60)];

    if ([creationDate compare:yesterDay] == NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        // creation date is before the Yesterday date
        res = [fm removeItemAtPath:[kDOCSFOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&err];

        if (!res && err) {
            NSLog(@"oops: %@", err);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this is right but i want to delet all files created before yesterday

Comment: in this it will only delete yesterdays files

Comment: It is quite straight forward make the necessary changes yo want.!

Answer (score 2):

If you would have searched little you would have got this:

```
 [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
```

So you can get creation date of your file using something like this:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary* dict = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[dict objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
```

Compare those date in if condition and delete those files.

> UPDATE 1:  Working code to delete files which are older than two days.

```
// Code to delete images older than two days.
   #define kDOCSFOLDER [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]

NSFileManager* fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDirectoryEnumerator* en = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:kDOCSFOLDER];    

NSString* file;
while (file = [en nextObject])
{
    NSLog(@"File To Delete : %@",file);
    NSError *error= nil;

    NSString *filepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:[kDOCSFOLDER stringByAppendingString:@"/%@"],file];


    NSDate   *creationDate =[[fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:filepath error:nil] fileCreationDate];
    NSDate *d =[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-2*24*60*60];

    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];// = [NSDateFormatter initWithDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEEE d"]; 

    NSString *createdDate = [df stringFromDate:creationDate];

     NSString *twoDaysOld = [df stringFromDate:d];

    NSLog(@"create Date----->%@, two days before date ----> %@", createdDate, twoDaysOld);

    // if ([[dictAtt valueForKey:NSFileCreationDate] compare:d] == NSOrderedAscending)
    if ([creationDate compare:d] == NSOrderedAscending)

    {
        if([file isEqualToString:@"RDRProject.sqlite"])
        {

            NSLog(@"Imp Do not delete");
        }

        else
        {
             [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[kDOCSFOLDER stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to remove all files i want day before yesterdays all files

Comment: @DilshadAlmani : Make sure you give proper heading to your question.

Comment: Agree with Devang.Please provide proper and clear description.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code for swift :

```
func cleanUp() {
    let maximumDays = 2.0
    let minimumDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-maximumDays*24*60*60)
    func meetsRequirement(date: Date) -> Bool { return date < minimumDate }

    func meetsRequirement(name: String) -> Bool { return name.hasPrefix(applicationName) && name.hasSuffix("log") }

    do {
        let manager = FileManager.default
        let documentDirUrl = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        if manager.changeCurrentDirectoryPath(documentDirUrl.path) {
            for file in try manager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: ".") {
                let creationDate = try manager.attributesOfItem(atPath: file)[FileAttributeKey.creationDate] as! Date
                if meetsRequirement(name: file) && meetsRequirement(date: creationDate) {
                    try manager.removeItem(atPath: file)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Cannot cleanup files: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
for (NSString *file in dirContents) {
    NSError *error= nil;
    NSDictionary *dictAtt = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:/*file path*/ error:&error];

    NSDate *d =[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-86400];
    if ([[dictAtt valueForKey:NSFileCreationDate] compare:d] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:/*file path*/ error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code gives warning in this line: ` if ([[dictAtt valueForKey:NSFileCreationDate] compare:d]`

Comment: its OK, its for date comparison

Comment: @anonymous what is the issue now.

Comment: NSlog(%@,dictAtt); add this line before NSDate *d =[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-86400]; this line and check what data is display.